# Ошибка при завершении установки Линукс

Tags: linux, установка

Решил установить второй ОС Линукс. Ещё при установке винды заранее отрезал часть диска, сейчас произвёл установку. По завершении установки появился экран загрузки платы и надпись вроде "Извлеките загрузочный носитель и нажмите энтер". После выполнения этих действий появился чёрный экран с таким текстом:

```
[ 1844.864433] sd-umoun [63992]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy 
[ 1844.865178] sd-umoun [63993]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy 
[ 1844.866474] shutdown [1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop0: Device or resource busy
[ 1844.867456] shutdown [1]: Failed to finalize file systems, loop devices, ignoring.
```

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему и чем она вызвана

Comment: Скорее всего это можно игнорировать